# How can I select the 1366x768 resolution for Ubuntu in VMware Player?

Tags: 12.10, resolution, vmware

Running Ubuntu 12.10 on VMware Player 5.0.1 build-894247.  I have installed the VMware Tools and can choose the resolution 800x600 and up to 2560x1600.  So I have a fair amount of resolutions to choose from.

But my laptops native resolution, and the one that Windows 7 is running on, is 1366x768.  Why can't I get that resolution in Ubuntu on VMware?  Those 3 extra pixels on each side is very annoying - especially when the mouse pointer moves there and directs the input outside Ubuntu.

Is there any way to edit the resolutions I can choose from in Ubuntu?